# Detecting filesystem changes without direct fs-support

Tags: linux, filesystems

How do I detect changes (additions, deletions, modifications) to a directory tree without filesystem support (like btrfs snapshots)?

I want to list all changes to a specific directory tree on an ext2 partition before and after running a certain program on Linux 3.18.5.

Comment: You could use inotify during the execution time of the application. You can select the file system events you're interested in and log those.

Comment: Simplest solution - copy directory and "diff" it. More sophisticated solution - some middle-ware between application and filesystem (like inotify). The answer depends on what information you can gather.